# How to auto upload record sound android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I'm a bit new in developing android application and I'm developing an Android Application that is supposed to auto-upload recorded sound as soon as they appear in the Media Store. How could i do this?

Comment: I did only the recording and save on phone for now.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327586/record-audio-and-upload-to-server-app

this may help you to record and auto upload the file to server.